# Programaticly create datasource for JBoss 4.2.x

Tags: java, jboss

Would it be possible to programmaticly create a data source in jboss and still have a valid jndi entry for the entity manager to use?

Creating the data source is where I am lost, I hope I can use a MBean that runs on stat-up to handle this.

This would not be my preferred method, but the application I am working on has a global configuration file hosted on another server I am suppose to use for configuration.

update: In this instance I need to create a data source programticly or change the jdbc url of an exsiting datasource. I don't know the DB server url until runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than poking around in the guts of JBoss in order to do this, I suggest using a 3rd-party connection pool utility, such as [Apache Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/index.html). There are instructions on how to programmatically register a DBCP datasource on JNDI [here](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/guide/jndi-howto.html).

The first two lines of the sample code should be unnecessary, just create the default `InitialContext` and then `rebind` the datasource reference into it as described.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=50303) a post that describes how to create a jboss service archive (SAR) that you can put in your EAR that will deploy a data source when the EAR is deployed, and remove it when the EAR in undeployed.