# How to bind JNDI datasource in webapp?

Tags: java, web-applications, datasource, jndi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programaticly create datasource for JBoss 4.2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857551/programaticly-create-datasource-for-jboss-4-2-x)

I'd like to bind JNDI DataSource in webapp (in servlet) for database connections.
Is it possible?
I have no glue how to do it.

I am able to lookup datasources defined in xml files in deploy directory, but the requirement is to add datasources dynamically.

It is for Jboss or Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks eis. Link helped.

Answer (score 0):

In a Tomcat web app you can find two instances of JNDI directory. A local one (per application context), and a [global one](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#Global_configuration).

To bind objects programmatically in the local one, you can use [javax.naming.Context.bind(String, Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#bind%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) as usual:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext(); 
ctx.bind("mykey", myobject);
```

In the other hand, you won't be able to dynamically bind resources to the global context as it is read-only.

Comment: I know how to bind some object in JNDI. Problem is that I didn't know how to bind/create DataSource for db connections (how to create DataSource object itself)